# Sorting a space delimited list with uneven spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, grep

I have a space delimited list that has an uneven amount of spaces in what *would* be the first column. I want to reverse sort this by the first number that appears after its string. I need to do this using bash commands.

Example:

```
Pontiac Firebird 19.0 6 250.0 100.0 3282. 15.0 71 US
Pontiac J2000 SE Hatchback 31.0 4 112.0 85.00 2575. 16.2 82 US
Oldsmobile Delta 88 Royale 12.0 8 350.0 160.0 4456. 13.5 72 US
Oldsmobile Omega 11.0 8 350.0 180.0 3664. 11.0 73 US
AMC Gremlin 20.0 6 232.0 100.0 2914. 16.0 75 US
AMC Gremlin 21.0 6 199.0 90.00 2648. 15.0 70 US
Pontiac Lemans V6 21.5 6 231.0 115.0 3245. 15.4 79 US
```

Would turn into:

```
Oldsmobile Omega 11.0 8 350.0 180.0 3664. 11.0 73 US
Oldsmobile Delta 88 Royale 12.0 8 350.0 160.0 4456. 13.5 72 US
Pontiac Firebird 19.0 6 250.0 100.0 3282. 15.0 71 US
AMC Gremlin 20.0 6 232.0 100.0 2914. 16.0 75 US
AMC Gremlin 21.0 6 199.0 90.00 2648. 15.0 70 US
Pontiac Lemans V6 21.5 6 231.0 115.0 3245. 15.4 79 US
Pontiac J2000 SE Hatchback 31.0 4 112.0 85.00 2575. 16.2 82 US
```

I've tried doing `sort -nr` to see what happens and it reverse sorts the list, but respective to it's alphabetized order. I want to sort based on all values.

The trick is that I **must** keep it space delimited. What's the best way to do this using bash?

Comment: you mean you want to sort on the first all-numeric field (which may contain a decimal)? so you ignore the `6` in `V6`, and you ignore the `2000` in `J2000`, right?  what are we supposed to do if there are duplicates in the 'first all-numeric field', ie, are there secondary/tertiary fields to use for sorting purposes?

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, precisely. if there are duplicates in the 'first all-numeric field', I would assume I'm able to put it in any order for those duplicates.

Comment: Are you sure the 'first all-numeric field' criterion works? 'Cause in the `Oldsmobile Delta 88 Royale 12.0 8 ...` line, that's the "88", not the "12.0".

Comment: Given that the first space-delimited string is a car model and you need advanced sorting capabilities, why don't you convince your team to store this data in a recognized structured format like CSV or TSV? Somebody might spend a couple of minutes to give you an answer, but those answers are not likely to pass the stress test on a large set of input values.

Answer (score 2):

> I **must** keep it space delimited

You mean, the **result** has to be space delimited again, right? During processing, you can transform the input however you like.

Assuming you know a character that never appears in your file otherwise, delimit the value you want to sort with by that character using `sed`, then sort by that value, then remove the additional delimiters again. (This process is basically a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).)

Here we use the bell character `\a` to delimit the key for sorting. It is very unlikely that that character is in a text file.

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) / \a\1\a /' | sort -t $'\a' -k2,2n | tr -d \\a
```

Comment: I believe the op should store the data in fault-proof format.

Answer (score 0):

here's a short ruby program:

```sh
ruby -e '
    puts IO.readlines(ARGV.shift, chomp: true)
        .map {|line|
            fields = line.split
            [fields[0..(fields.size - 9)].join(" ")] + fields[-8 .. -1]
        }
        .sort_by {|row| row[1]}
        .map {|row| row.join(" ")}
        .join("\n")
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
Pontiac Firebird 19.0 6 250.0 100.0 3282. 15.0 71 US
Pontiac J2000 SE Hatchback 31.0 4 112.0 85.00 2575. 16.2 82 US
Oldsmobile Delta 88 Royale 12.0 8 350.0 160.0 4456. 13.5 72 US
Oldsmobile Omega 11.0 8 350.0 180.0 3664. 11.0 73 US
AMC Gremlin 20.0 6 232.0 100.0 2914. 16.0 75 US
AMC Gremlin 21.0 6 199.0 90.00 2648. 15.0 70 US
Pontiac Lemans V6 21.5 6 231.0 115.0 3245. 15.4 79 US
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]*[.][0-9]*";PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"}{arr[$1]=$0}END{for(i in arr){print arr[i]}}' file.txt
```

output

```
Oldsmobile Omega 11.0 8 350.0 180.0 3664. 11.0 73 US
Oldsmobile Delta 88 Royale 12.0 8 350.0 160.0 4456. 13.5 72 US
Pontiac Firebird 19.0 6 250.0 100.0 3282. 15.0 71 US
AMC Gremlin 20.0 6 232.0 100.0 2914. 16.0 75 US
AMC Gremlin 21.0 6 199.0 90.00 2648. 15.0 70 US
Pontiac Lemans V6 21.5 6 231.0 115.0 3245. 15.4 79 US
Pontiac J2000 SE Hatchback 31.0 4 112.0 85.00 2575. 16.2 82 US
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is 0 or more digits followed by literal dot (`[.]`) followed by 0 or more digits (note: I assume that there will always be dot in first number and never dot in column with name) and that array traversal should be treat-indices-as-numbers-ascending which is one of [Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html). For each line I add to array pair with key being first number (`$1`) and value being whole line (`$0`). After going through all lines I `print` values from array `arr` with order which observe selected array traversal.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*